# Problems with Cmakelists.txt for OSX/Windows compilation

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, glfw

I'm attempting to alter my CmakeLists.txt file for my currently working MacOSX version of my OpenGL engine, so that it will compile and run on windows. I'm positive that I'm doing something wrong in the way I'm writing my Cmakelists.txt and would like some help correcting it.

Have already tried a multitude of different tutorials and examples found online. The problem most likely lies in how I'm trying to link dll files but I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -w")
project (sake)

add_subdirectory(src/imgui)
add_subdirectory(libs/assimp)
add_subdirectory(src/GLM/glm)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

file(GLOB SRC_FILES src/*.cpp)

add_executable(sake ${SRC_FILES})

target_link_libraries(sake imgui)
target_link_libraries(sake assimp)


# glfw


if (WIN32)
    add_subdirectory(F:/glfw-3.3 F:/glfw-3.3/src)
    include_directories(F:/glfw-3.3/include)
    link_libraries(${GLFW_LIBRARY_DIRS})
endif (WIN32)
if(APPLE)
    find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_libraries(${GLFW_LIBRARY_DIRS})
endif (APPLE)



# opengl
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# glew
if(WIN32)
    include_directories(F:/GLEW/glew-2.1.0/include)
endif (WIN32)

if(APPLE)
    find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif (APPLE)

if(WIN32)
    include_directories(libs/assimp/include)
endif(WIN32)

if(APPLE)
    find_package(assimp REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${ASSIMP_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif(APPLE)

if (APPLE)
    find_library(COCOA_LIBRARY Cocoa)
    find_library(OpenGL_LIBRARY OpenGL)
    find_library(IOKIT_LIBRARY IOKit)
    find_library(COREVIDEO_LIBRARY CoreVideo)
    SET(EXTRA_LIBS ${COCOA_LIBRARY} ${OpenGL_LIBRARY} ${IOKIT_LIBRARY} ${COREVIDEO_LIBRARY})
endif (APPLE)

target_link_libraries(
        sake
        glfw
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
        ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
        ${EXTRA_LIBS}
)

add_custom_target(run
    COMMAND ./sake
    DEPENDS sake
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}
)
```

current error message happens when I `cmake .`

```
CMake Error at F:/glfw-3.3/src/CMakeLists.txt:95 (add_library):
  add_library cannot create target "glfw" because another target with the
  same name already exists.  The existing target is a shared library created
  in source directory "F:/glfw-3.3/src".  See documentation for policy
  CMP0002 for more details.
```

Comment: Just use `find_package` in WIN32 case too, like you do in APPLE case. This is proper way to locate dependencies.

Comment: Call `add_subdirectory(F:/glfw-3.3 F:/glfw-3.3/src)` uses the first argument (`F:/glfw-3.3`) as the **source** directory and the second argument (`F:/glfw-3.3/src`) as the **build** directory for subproject. According to the error message you already have `CMakeLists.txt` in the build directory, which is definitely **wrong**. You should select build directory which is initially empty (not exists).

Comment: @arrowd When I use ```find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)```, I recieve this error 



```CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findglfw3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3" with any of
  the following names:

    glfw3Config.cmake
    glfw3-config.cmake

```

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried what you suggested, but no change. I did try a solution clean and ```cmake .``` as well. Still the same error.

Comment: " I tried what you suggested, but no change." - What **exactly** have you tried?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I apologize, I got a little mixed up on my end. 
What I tried was changing the line 
```add_subdirectory(F:/glfw-3.3 F:/glfw-3.3/src)```
to this
```add_subdirectory(F:/glfw-3.3/src F:/glfw-3.3/build)```.
However, I did it in my imgui CMakeLists.txt and not my main CmakeLists.txt.
I now have an error which says 
```Error at CMakeLists.txt:25 (add_subdirectory):
  The binary directory
    F:/glfw-3.3/build
  is already used to build a source directory.  It cannot be used to build
  source directory
    F:/glfw-3.3/src
  Specify a unique binary directory name.
```

Comment: As I said, build directory should be empty. If you use it before, just remove it (or cleanup).

Comment: @Tsyvarev so I've added     

```file(REMOVE_RECURSE F:/glfw-3.3/build)
add_subdirectory(F:/glfw-3.3/src F:/glfw-3.3/build)``` 

to my CmakeLists.txt file, with no change in the error message. How can I successfully empty the build directory AFTER imgui also builds glfw3?

Comment: "AFTER imgui also builds glfw3?" - Do you mean that imgui builds glfw3 too? If so, why do you build glfw3 manually after this? Just use targets created by previous building.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: It depends what do you want to do with glfw3. Start with removing `add_subdirectory(F:/glfw-3.3/src ...)` line.